# How to click a button and scrape text from a website using python scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have used python **scrapy** to extract data from a website. Now i am able to scrape most of the details of a site using scrapy. But my main problem is that iam not able to extract all the reviews of products from the site. I am only able to extract the top 4 reviews which they display on the page and for getting other reviews i have to go to a **pop up window** which has all the reviews. I looked for 'href' for the popup window but im not able to find it. This is the link that i tried to scrape. The reviews and ratings are at the bottom of the page: https://www.coursera.org/learn/big-data-introduction

Can any one help me by explaining how to extract the reviews from this popup window. Another think to note is that there is infinite scrolling for the pop up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy, unlike tools like Selenium and PhantomJS, does not drive a full web browser in the background. You cannot just click a button.

You need to understand what the button does (e.g. does it simply submit a form? Does it do something with JavaScript? Etc.) and reproduce the functionality in your own code.

For example, you might need to read the content of a `script` element, apply regular expressions to it to pull a URL from a string literal, then make a new HTTP request to that URL, the pell the data you want from the new DOM.

... and then repeat for the next “page” of the infinite scroll.